# switch with char1

Tags: java

I'm trying to use switch on Java 6 with parameter type char 1
but I am getting an error "cannot convert char to string",what am I doing wrong here?

```
public static void setRoot(Element rootTreeNode,char type ) {

    switch (type) {
    case "a":
```

I want that the case will be on char1.

Comment: Double-quotes denote a `String`.

Comment: What is char1? your types here ar char and String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Single quotes** `' '` , **Double quotes are used to represent** `String`, and `char` is represented in Java with **Single quotes**.

```
switch (type) {
    case 'a':
```

Answer (score 4):

`"a"` is not a char but a string. You should use **single quotes**(`'a'`), to match a character: -

```
switch(type) { 
   case 'a':
}
```

Comment: Thanks!Btw,how can i define filed type char1 in java ?

Comment: @BorisMandovskes. Are you talking about data type char1, then no, there is no datatype as char1, its just `char`. If you are talking about variable name, then: - `char char1;` will do it.

Comment: @BorisMandovskes And remember to accept this as an answer by clicking the arrow besides the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 switch (type)
  { case 'a' :
```

notice the single quotes

single quotes represents char in java whereas double quotes represents string. hence the error you getting

Comment: @JohanSjöberg . i mean single quotes, ' ' , n double quotes " "